# Error when I run the command: rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the steps given here :  [Understanding Topics](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics)

I get the following error:

```
Inspiron-5559:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinect-rqt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinect-rqt
```

**When I run rqt :**
[image: image description]

**When I run the command :**

```
Inspiron-5559:~$ rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph
Could not import "pyqt" bindings of qt_gui_cpp library - so C++ plugins will not be available:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui_cpp/cpp_binding_helper.py", line 43, in <module>
    from . import libqt_gui_cpp_sip
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_libqt_gui_cpp_sip)

[WARN] [1518230850.310686]: Failed to load Python extension for LZ4 support. LZ4 compression will not be available.
RosPluginProvider.load(rqt_graph/RosGraph) exception raised in __builtin__.__import__(rqt_graph.ros_graph, [RosGraph]):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/ros_plugin_provider.py", line 80, in load
    module = __builtin__.__import__(attributes['module_name'], fromlist=[attributes['class_from_class_type']], level=0)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 45, in <module>
    from qt_dotgraph.dot_to_qt import DotToQtGenerator
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_dotgraph/dot_to_qt.py", line 36, in <module>
    import pydot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydot'

PluginManager._load_plugin() could not load plugin "rqt_graph/RosGraph":
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler.py", line 99, in load
    self._load()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler_direct.py", line 54, in _load
    self._plugin = self._plugin_provider.load(self._instance_id.plugin_id, self._context)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 71, in load
    instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 71, in load
    instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui_py/ros_py_plugin_provider.py", line 60, in load
    return super(RosPyPluginProvider, self).load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 71, in load
    instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/ros_plugin_provider.py", line 86, in load
    raise e
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/ros_plugin_provider.py", line 80, in load
    module = __builtin__.__import__(attributes['module_name'], fromlist=[attributes['class_from_class_type']], level=0)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 45, in <module>
    from qt_dotgraph.dot_to_qt import DotToQtGenerator
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_dotgraph/dot_to_qt.py", line 36, in <module>
    import pydot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydot'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282298/error-when-i-run-the-command:-rosrun-rqt_graph-rqt_graph/) by [nrb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33066/nrb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2018-02-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> E: Unable to locate package ros-kinect-rqt
> ```

Wrong prefix. I think you mean `ros-kinetic`.

> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydot'
> ```

[rqt_graph depends on](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_graph/blob/90117a0b04c99d1baf4589dc97751fa3487883a4/package.xml#L26) `qt_dotgraph`, which [depends on](https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/blob/ab6dbb2f0b7b8dc512e4338b6e4d36f2261237bc/qt_dotgraph/package.xml#L18) `python-pydot`. So by the official, formal way of installation like the following, it should be installed.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rqt-graph
[sudo] password for n130s: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python-pydot ros-kinetic-qt-dotgraph
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-pydot ros-kinetic-qt-dotgraph ros-kinetic-rqt-graph
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 71.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 361 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1